# Per-environment config in create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app, react-native-config

I have an app that I created using create-react-native-app. I'm trying to use react-native-config to manage config variables that differ between dev and production.

This requires the following steps, which depend on Xcode. Is there any way to do this without ejecting my project?

```
Go to your project -> Build Settings -> All 
* Set Preprocess Info.plist File to Yes
* Set Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File to ${BUILD_DIR}/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h
* Set Info.plist Other Preprocessor Flags to -traditional
```